# Meaning of "As music rubber hosed the air"

Tags: meaning

"Irrational youths stop to stare, as music rubber hosed the air."

Music rubber? or rubber as music? Hosed the air - what may it mean?

It comes from the song Angry Again by Megadeth

Comment: source please. Is this quoted from somewhere? It looks like lyrics, in which case consider poetic licence.

Comment: This looks like poetry/lyrics, where as you might expect, the language is "unusual". Purely my own opinion, but I'm guessing *rubber-hosed*  (beaten with a length of rubber hose) - which I personally would hyphenate in this context - is meant to invoke a sense of ***brash, callous*** treatment (the youths were effectively being "tortured" by (loud) music filling the air around them. But nobody would use language like this in normal conversational contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The allusion here is to the use of [rubber hose to beat people](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hosed&page=3) without leaving bruises. You sometimes see t[v cops talking about beating](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/45z5zj/why_do_cops_on_tv_talk_about_beating_people_with/) a confession using a 50cm length of heavy rubber hose.

These are lyrics, the music "rubber-hosed" the air is figurative. The loud music "beats-up" the air.